# Prove that for all integers a,b,n,if n=a+b,then a≤n/2 or b≤n/2 using proof by contradiction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using proof of contradiction, I've tried using the method but my answer isn't looking right, what rule should I use

Comment: Take $a \gt n/2$ and $b \gt n/2$, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you may be quite new to the idea of 'proof by contradiction' and so I will try to guide you step by step a bit.

If you want to use proof by contradiction to prove $A$ implies $B$, always start with assuming "not $B$" and try to show "not $A$".

Like I said start with "not ( $a\leq n/2$ or $b\leq n/2$)", you may quickly realize it is equivalent to 
"$a,b>n/2$", which was what @BillyJoe hinted. In this case the sum will be greater than $n$ and so you see "not A".

Comment: thanks so much !

Comment: @p4ph5x no problem!